# Google Chrome automatic client certificate select

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, client-certificates, policy

I'm aware that you can pre-select a client certificate by setting a Chrome policy. There are a lot of samples around.

The problem is that all samples I found always refer to the "ISSUER" as filter

{"pattern":"SOME_URL","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"SOME_CN"}}}

My problem now is that I need to use the SUBJECT CN as filter as I have a lot of certs issued by the same Issuer CN

I'm trying this:

{"pattern":"SOME_URL","filter":{"SUBJECT":{"CN":"SOME_CN"}}}

Chrome would not accept that and prompt for a certificate. The chrome://policy would show the above (with SUBJECT) correctly

Is it possible or am I trying to do something impossible and there is only a single filter possibility??

I couldn't fine any documentation on the possible "filter" parameter options.

Thanks for your help!
Alex

Comment: Did you ever find any solution to this?

Comment: No, it's not supported. Still struggle with that ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following policy file (written in json) has worked for me for quite some time (years).

```
{
  "AutoSelectCertificateForUrls": [
    "{\"pattern\":\"https://somehost0.com/\",\"filter\":{\"SUBJECT\":{\"CN\":\"Testuser test login 01\"}}}",
    "{\"pattern\":\"https://somehost1.com/\",\"filter\":{\"SUBJECT\":{\"CN\":\"Testuser test register 01\"}}}",
  ]
}
```

We use this in test automation with a *Google Chrome* in a *Linux* container.